# Firebug showing HTTP 302 error in red (no errors in apache error log)

Tags: javascript, iphone, firebug, http-status-code-302, http-error

I am experiencing a problem on the mobile version of my site where I get a HTTP `302 Found` message in Firebug on Firefox, but the message is in red. I am spoofing Firefox to switch the User Agent string to mimic an iPhone, this lets me debug the mobile site on a desktop.

The problem is I cannot understand why I would get a blank response for my request, *particularly* when I don't get any errors in the Apache error log.

Where should I be focusing my attention on for this problem? I don't have this issue on the desktop site, which shares back-end functionality - it only occurs on mobile.

I'm also getting no JavaScript errors in the console.

[image: 302 Firebug]

Comment: Hope its a same origin policy issue. Your page is in HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this error/warning is caused by a mixture of crossing protocols (HTTP->HTTPS) and also that the Firebug plugin for Firefox displays this scenario in red (making you believe an error has occurred).

My investigations have led me to believe that using JSONP, instead of JSON, when crossing protocols in this fashion will help.

Answer (score 0):

The status code 302 means that the browser should open a different URL. Take a look at the headers, then you see the URL next to "Location:". Maybe there is something wrong with that URL.

The reason this does not happen with the desktop version could be that there is either no need to redirect (only the mobile site is at a different URL) or only the redirect for the mobile version is wrong.